# Post to multiple friends walls with one action

Tags: api, post, facebook-graph-api

I have seen an app where I can post to multiple friends' walls in one action. Basically the user will check a box for each friend and then hit a post button and each of the friends that were checked have a wall post now.

I thought this wasn't allowed. Did something change or is the app not in compliance with the Policies?

Answer (score 2):

Can each post to friends' walls be delayed/scheduled using CRON so that there is a delay in each post. This way, I think, one can escape penalty from Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

By gaining the publish_stream permission you can carry out this functionality.

From here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

publish_stream

Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

You can then utilise the Graph Api to perform these functions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I just didn't realize that I could display a friend list and have a user check their friends' pictures and then add one message for all of them and click a single button click that it would post to all of my friends that I selected walls.

Nothing that I can see in the policies limits sending multiple wall posts with one action.

Comment: From that same page, they refer to the fact it is best practice for this to come from a user generated event, as opposed to a php/server function automating them.

To display the users friends you will also need read_friendlists permission, which will allow you to get all the friends ID and names. With this you could then carry out the functionality